# selenium парсинг сайта

Tags: python, парсер, selenium

```
import json

import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

class Parse:
    def __init__(self, url:str, items:list, count:int=30, version_main=None):
        self.url = url
        self.items = items
        self.count = count
        self.version_main = version_main
        self.data = []

    def __set_up(self):
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument('--headless')
        self.driver = uc.Chrome(version_main = self.version_main ,options=options)

    def __get_url(self):
        self.driver.get(self.url)

    def __paginator(self):
        while self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[data-marker='pagination-button/nextPage']") and self.count > 0 :
            self.__parse_page()
            self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-marker='pagination-button/nextPage']").click()
            self.count -= 1
    def __parse_page(self):
        titles = self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-marker='item']")
        for title in titles:
            name = title.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[itemprop='name']").text
            description = title.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class*='item-description']").text
            url = title.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-marker='item-title']").get_attribute("href")
            price = title.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[itemprop='price']").get_attribute("content")
            data = {
                'name' : name,
                'description' : description,
                'url' : url,
                'price' : price
            }
            if any([item.lower() in description for item in self.items]) and int(price) == 0:
                self.data.append(data)
                print(data)
            #print(name, description, url, price)
        self.__save_data()
    def __save_data(self):
        with open("items.json", "w", encoding='utf-8') as f :
            json.dump(self.data, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

    def parse(self):
        self.__set_up()
        self.__get_url()
        self.__paginator()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Parse(url='https://www.avito.ru/krasnoyarsk?cd=1&q=%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE',
          count=3,
          version_main=115,
          items=["iphone", "телевизор"]
          ).parse()
```

делал всё по [гайду с ютуба](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pbzPkZcVOx0), вылазит ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DEXP\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\selenum\main.py", line 56, in <module>
    Parse(url='https://www.avito.ru/krasnoyarsk?cd=1&q=%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE',
  File "C:\Users\DEXP\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\selenum\main.py", line 53, in parse
    self.__paginator()
  File "C:\Users\DEXP\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\selenum\main.py", line 25, in __paginator
    self.__parse_page()
  File "C:\Users\DEXP\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\selenum\main.py", line 31, in __parse_page
    name = title.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[itemprop='name']").text
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Answer (score 1):

По ошибке можно понять, что при `find_elements` вы получаете объект `list`.

Если вы подразумеваете, что элемент один, используйте `find_element` (без `s`). Он вам вернёт нужный объект.